# Raspberry Pi 3B - Headless - No Internet - Ethernet LAN - Router IP Assigned - Error to Connect

Tags: ssh, ethernet, headless, putty

Don't know what I am doing wrong but since I had connected Pi to router's LAN port, I am not able to SSH via any OS. Be it Linux or Windows. I am able to connect it easily if I choose WiFi over Ethernet. But my requirement if to use a direct wired connection for internet.

Steps taken:

1. RPi with latest Stretch Lite
2. Blank ssh file in /boot dir
3. Connect LAN (Yellow/Interent) port
4. Putty to SSH to IP/Name
5. Error: Host Not Found/Not Reachable

What is wrong here?

Comment: Does DHCP is enabled on the router's LAN port? What IP/name do you use? Where do you get it from? Does you have access to the router? Can you configure it?

Comment: "What is wrong here?" who knows, because you haven't said what you did (as distinct from your intentions) or posted any diagnostics. What is this "(Yellow/Interent) port"?

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for the board failing to run normally is a weedy power supply. The 3B & 3B+ boards need at least 2.5A at 5.1V and a good quality cable between the wall wart and your raspberry.

Try upgrading your power supply to that minimum spec.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had several Raspberry Pi's that I was reimaging after I plugged the first one in I realized I forgot to set it up properly. I then made changes to all of the SD Cards. The first Raspberry Pi did not work, but all of the other ones did. I had to reimage the SD Card, insert the ssh file, and then it worked.

You have to create the ssh file before the first boot. If you boot the SD Card once and it isn't customized, it will not work as expected.

- Image the SD Card
- Make the necessary changes
- Then first boot